# Property 'paginator' and 'sort' has no initializer

Tags: angular, angular15

I am trying to create a form filter based on the example on this website.However, I found that the code is having issues in my environment.

[Data table with sorting, pagination, and filtering.](https://next.material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-overview)

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
```

> Property 'paginator' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
>
> Property 'sort' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

These two code segments are causing errors in Visual Studio Code.

According to the information on the Internet, I changed the above two pieces of code to

```
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator | any = {};
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort = new MatSort();
```

Although the code can already be compiled and searchable, it still cannot to sort the table.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to initialize anything. Just find tsconfig.json file and in "compilerOptions" add this line "strictPropertyInitialization": false

Example

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
  },
```